# Using a while loop with an element childNodes.length until it is equal with a specified number doesn't work (while loop can't be exited)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build an Instagram script to retrieve a list of people who don't follow you back.

My idea looks like this:

-> open followers tab -> scroll down until all of the followers are shown in the DOM -> add them to an array -> close the tab -> open following tab -> scroll down until all of the following are shown in the DOM -> add them to array -> compare the arrays -> display who doesn't follow you back

That's what I've done so far:

```js
    selectors = {
         modal: "Y8-fY",
         objList: "isgrP",
         divList: "PZuss"
    };
    x = {};
    x.following = [];
    x.followers = [];
    numberOfFollowers = Number(document.getElementsByClassName(selectors.modal)[1].querySelector('a').querySelector('span').title);
    numberOfFollowing = Number(document.getElementsByClassName(selectors.modal)[2].querySelector('a').querySelector('span').innerHTML);

var openFollowersTab = function()
{
    document.getElementsByClassName(selectors.modal)[1].querySelector('a').click();
}

openFollowersTab();

var showFollowers = function (x)
{ 
    document.querySelector("." + selectors.objList).scrollTop = 200;
    document.querySelector("." + selectors.objList).scrollTop = -200;
    while(document.querySelector(".PZuss").childNodes.length != x)
    {
        document.querySelector("." + selectors.objList).scrollTop += 1000;
    }
}
```

This code has two small problems which I don't know how to deal with.
First of all, if I call showFollowers() in the script, the page breaks because of the while loop. I can't seem to get why though. In my head this should've been working. In that ".PZuss" are located all of the followers as a li. So until it is equal with the numberOfFollowers, it should scroll down.

I know there should be only one problem per question but this is a small one and I find it even stranger than the first one - until I introduced that while condition (and the code worked, but not how I wanted) if I have called showFollowers()) in the code it said it can't find .PZuss. .PZuss appears in the DOM after the followersTab is opened so I thought I would have to do something like this so the tab is opened first:

```js
setTimeout(showFollowers(numberOfFollowers), 10000);
```

but it doesn't work either. If I run showFollowers() in the console AFTER the OpenFollowersTab() is closed, everything worked fine. (again, without that while loop).

So the main problem is why that WHILE doesn't work because I find that very strange. If you could give me an insight of how I should wait for the DOM from the followers tab to be loaded, that would be great too, if not, it's fine, I'll find a workaround.

Thanks a lot for your time!
Have a great day!

Comment: What is the HTML?

Comment: You need to create snippet for the problem.

Comment: scrolling anything doesn't change the number of childNodes some container has. That's why your `while`-loop is an infinite-loop. Nothing that happens inside your loop has any influence on the condition of that loop. Therefore the loop will either not run at all, or run indefinitely (for about 30s)

Comment: I can't really create a snippet/show HTML because it changes when I open the followersTab, scroll down, ect. Can you just please enter your instagram page profile and try my code there?

Comment: @Thomas when I scroll down on my list of followers, new followers appear in the DOM. How should I run my idea then?

Comment: `Display !== DOM` *"How should I run my idea then?"* I don't fully understand your idea and I have no clue what your markup *(and therefore the DOM)* looks like.

Comment: I would love to give you the HTML but I can't because as I told you above it changes everytime. (when I scroll down on the list of followers new <li> items with new followers appear, ect). I also don't really know where is the HTML, because in the main .html file it isn't.

Comment: I don't use instagram, but your approach definitely seems like it could work, I'm assuming that Instagram auto loads new results when scrolling down, hence one might expect more DOM nodes to be added by 'changing the view'. However,  auto loading more results maybe triggered differently / combination of events (maybe even to prevent such auto crawling through the UI). I can't check, 'cause I don't have any... But maybe it is better to learn working with Instagram/Hatebook's Graph-API... I assume retrieving this type of information should be possible.